# How to display stage value changed in opportunities in last 7 days on reports?

Tags: reporting, admin, custom-reports, report-chart

Stage value changed from "prospect" to "closed won"  in last 7 days

how to write filter logic for that?

How can I display only those records on reports?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Opportunity History" report for this. When creating a new report, select "Opportunity History" in the report type. In the filters, you can select From Stage and To Stage to filter on. See the attached screenshot. 
[image]